# Two animations in one sprite in andengine

Tags: android, andengine

This is possible to add two animations to one sprite? 
This is my code:

```
public class MainGameActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {

    private int width, height;
    private Scene scene;
    private Camera camera;

    private BitmapTextureAtlas textureBanana;
    private TiledTextureRegion regionBanana;
    private AnimatedSprite spriteBanana;

    private static int spriteColumns = 4;
    private static int spriteRows = 2;

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        width = size.x;
        height = size.y;

        camera = new Camera(0, 0, width, height);
        EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(
                width, height), camera);

        return engineOptions;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreateResources() {

        textureBanana = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(), 256, 128, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
        regionBanana = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(textureBanana, getAssets(), "gfx/spr_banana.png", 0, 0, spriteColumns, spriteRows);

        textureBanana.load();
    }

    @Override
    protected Scene onCreateScene() {

        scene = new Scene();
        scene.setBackground(new Background(Color.WHITE));

        spriteBanana = new AnimatedSprite(width/2, height/2, regionBanana, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        scene.attachChild(spriteBanana);
        spriteBanana.animate(50);

        return scene;
    }

}
```

This code show animation of happy banana. Now I want to start rotate this banana on 360 degree in 20 seconds. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add as many animations you like.
heres how:

20f(20s) is time increase to slow decrease to make it faster .then 0 to 360

```
RotationModifier rotate = new RotationModifier(20f, 0, 360);
spriteBanana.registerEntityModifier(rotate); // delete this line if you want endless
```

if you want to repeat it endless.

```
spriteBanana.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(rotate))));
```